# Is the community moderating?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I flagged two questions as off-topic last week, the first flag is now almost 8 days old. Of course I don't necessarily expect the community to agree with me on these flags, but I'm surprised that they haven't been handled in over a week.

Now, the moderators could certainly handle those flags quickly, and guess this will happen after this meta post is published. But I'm concerned that the community doesn't seem to use the review queue enough to ensure that flags are handled.

Is this just a fluke, or is there a problem with the involvement of the community in moderation?

Comment: I would guess that it is simply that the community is not yet engaged in moderation enough to handle these flags, and that we have not attracted a large enough user base yet to get more response on various review tasks.

Comment: I think that there is a problem with community moderation. I talked about this problem in my meta post, [We need more Community Moderation](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/352/we-need-more-community-moderation)

Comment: I’m very confused. At this moment these both appear to still be pending in your flagged posts history. However, neither of them shows up as a flag for me to handle. I think most of the mods check in most days, and we certainly haven’t ignored any flags for a week. There simply haven’t been any when I’ve logged in in recent days, including now (on either meta or main).

Comment: @Susan Those flags don't go into the flag queue for moderators, they put the post into the close review queue

Comment: Oh, I get it - because they’re not really functioning as flags (the way I think about them) but as nominations for VTC, except you don’t have VTC privileges. Sorry, I was lost for a minute. Yes, true, I’ve sometimes gone into that queue and found stuff lingering for quite a while.